# Why am I getting an error in my ASP.NET Core SQL Server Express Connection String?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, connection-string

I've recently started a new ASP.NET Core web application and I'd like to connect it to my local SQLExpress database.  I've been following the documentation but I'm getting an error of "Value cannot be null" when it tries to read my connection string at

`options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")`

Here is my code so far.  In `Startup.cs` I have the following setup:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Blondie.CoreApiSql.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace Blondie.CoreApiSql
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>
                (options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddMvc();
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

When you run the appliation the error is triggered at the following line:

`services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext> (options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));`

I have defined the connection string in the `appsettings.json` as described in the documentation which is as follows:

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=DESKTOP-PC009\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Senua;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    },
    "Logging": {
      "IncludeScopes": false,
      "Debug": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Warning"
        }
      },
      "Console": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Warning"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I have already created the `Senua` database with a table in it which has no data.  My database uses windows authentication.

I have defined my database context in the following manner with my single table.

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) 
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Hellheim> Hellheim { get; set; }
}
```

It was my understanding that this error is only typically visibly if you've failed to define your connection string in the `appsettings.json` file but I've already added it, has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: why did you declare the configuration as ```private``` should be```public IConfiguration configuration;```

Comment: @JohnNyingi: It doesn't matter, and certainly doesn't affect anything having to do with the OP's issue here.

Comment: Seems `configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")` is returning null for some reason. Debug and verify. It could be something as a simple typo somewhere, either in Startup or in your config.

Comment: Where do you assign a value to `configuration`? i.e. It looks like `configuration` is `null` given that you don't show it being set anywhere in your code.

Comment: He's missing the assign. At least a constructor definition to assign the configuration since its dependent on dependency injection

Comment: I think that is the problem.  If I manually put the string into the GetConnectionString it works.  The documentation is missing the assign which is why I've also missed it.  Can anyone perhaps show how that would look?

Comment: `public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) { this.configuration = configuration; }` (assuming ASP.NET Core 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define and assign a value to Configuration its of `IConfiguration` and requires a value.
Define the Dependency Injection in the constructor

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you for all the help everyone :)