# asp.net core code first Cannot open database "DbName" requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, code-first

I have a asp.net core 3.1 code first project in Visual Studio 2019 and SQL Server 2017

It gives this exception when I make a request to the database:
Cannot open database "DbName" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'sa'.

It was in Log SQL server:
Login failed for user 'NT Service\SSISScaleOutMaster150'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: ]

I tried most of the solutions on the internet but none of them worked

Other info:
Named pipes are enabled
TCP/IP is enabled
Remote connections are allowed
I even removed the SQL server and reinstalled it and update Visual studio
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119602/how-to-make-sql-server-find-a-login-matching-the-name-provided) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575907/cannot-open-database-test-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-fail) but didn't work

when i create database manually the exception changed to :Invalid object name 'User'.

connection string:

```
    "myconn": "Server=.;Database=onlineShopDB;User Id=sa;password=qazwsxedc;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
  },
```

configure service:

```
        {

            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddDbContext<OnlineShopContext>(item => item.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("myconn")));

            services.AddScoped<IDataRepository<User>, UserRepository>();
        
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }
```

repositoty class:

```
public class UserRepository : IDataRepository<User>
    {
        private readonly OnlineShopContext _onlineShopContext;
        public UserRepository(OnlineShopContext onlineShopContext)
        {
            _onlineShopContext = onlineShopContext;
        }

        public void Add(User entity)
        {
            _onlineShopContext.Users.Add(entity);
            _onlineShopContext.SaveChanges();
        }      
       
    }
```

IDataRepository:

```
 public interface IDataRepository<TEntity>
    {
        IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
        TEntity Get(long id);
        void Add(TEntity entity);
        void Update(TEntity dbEntity, TEntity entity);
        void Delete(TEntity entity);
    }
```

onlineShopContext:

```
 public class OnlineShopContext:DbContext
    {
        public OnlineShopContext(DbContextOptions options):base(options)
        { }
        public virtual DbSet<UserType> UserTypes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ProductFeatures> ProductFeatures { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ProductImages> GetProductImages { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<OrderStatus> OrderStatuses { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<OrderItems> OrderItems { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)  
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserType>().HasData(
                new UserType() { Id = 1, Name = "User", Title = "a" },
                new UserType() { Id = 2, Name = "Admin", Title = "b" });

            
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Please check the error log on SQL server `exec sp_readerrorlog`  and include it in your question

Comment: Just checking, can you definitely access the database using those sa credentials via SSMS?

Comment: yes, I can login to SSMS with the 'sa' account and windows authentication

Comment: the error log on sql server is : Login failed for user 'NT Service\SSISScaleOutMaster140'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

Comment: If you're using the 'sa' account in SSMS then you're not using windows authentication, you're using SQL authentication.

Comment: I mean, I tried both methods

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. OK, when you log in as 'sa', using SQL authentication, are you able to switch to the onlineShopDB database? It's possible for the sa<->dbo mapping to become disconnected, in which case connecting to master and running `alter authorization on database::onlineShopDB to  sa` does the trick.

Comment: thank for your comment, i'm using code first approach and  onlineShopDB database doesn't exist

Comment: Well, your connection string specifies it: `Database=onlineShopDB`. It sounds like you're not actually creating your entities?

Comment: See, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49721742/ef-code-first-not-creating-the-database)

Comment: thank allmhuran, your link was useful and solved my problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF code first not creating the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49721742/ef-code-first-not-creating-the-database)